# Scala Mutable Option?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

I want something like this:

```
private val cachedResponse = mutable.Option.empty[A]

def get: A = cachedResponse getOrElseUpdate db.findModel()

def update: Unit = {
  db.updateModel
  cachedResponse.empty()    // set it to None/Option.empty
}
```

I am not looking for a generic HashMap based memoization [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129721/how-does-this-scala-memo-works). I tried implementing it using a `var Option[A]` but it did not look very idiomatic to me:

```
private var cachedResponse: Option[A] = None

def get: A = cachedResponse getOrElse {
 cachedResponse = Option(db.findModel())
 cachedResponse.get
}

def update: Unit = {
  db.updateModel
  cachedResponse = None
}
```

Comment: A quick googling found this implementation which looks like what you want...: http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=689

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one built into the standard library.

Using a `var` containing an immutable `Option` is the idiomatic way to do it (assuming you can't rewrite this to not use state at all).

Otherwise, you should build your own.  Here's the core of an implementation:

```
class MutableOpt[A] {
  private[this] var myValue: A = _
  private[this] var loaded = false
  private def valueEquals(o: Any) = myValue == o
  def get = if (loaded) myValue else throw new NoSuchElementException("MutableOpt")
  def set(a: A): this.type = { loaded = true; myValue = a; this }
  def getOrSet(a: => A): A = {
    if (!loaded) {
      myValue = a
      loaded = true
    }
    myValue
  }
  def isEmpty = !loaded
  def nonEmpty = loaded
  def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = if (loaded) f(myValue)
  def transform(f: A => A): this.type = { if (loaded) myValue = f(myValue); this }
  def clear(): this.type = { loaded = false; this }
  def toOption = if (loaded) Some(myValue) else None
  override def toString = if (loaded) "MutableOpt("+myValue.toString+")" else "MutableOpt()"
  override def hashCode = if (loaded) myValue.hashCode else 1751
  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case m: MutableOpt[_] =>
      (isEmpty && m.isEmpty) || (nonEmpty && m.nonEmpty && m.valueEquals(myValue))
    case _ => false
  }
}
object MutableOpt {
  def from[A](o: Option[A]) = {
    val m = new MutableOpt[A]
    o match {
      case Some(a) => m set a
      case _ =>
    }
    m
  }
}
```

Define together with `:paste` if using the REPL.

Comment: LGTM. Thanks for sharing. But, there might be some race condition in getrSet in a multi threaded environment..

Comment: True, that is exactly one of the advantages of immutability over mutability.

Comment: @wrick - Absolutely, just like with almost everything mutable.  You could make all the operations atomic, but performance would suffer.